# DropDownList não carrega em cadeia

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dropdown

Tenho um método em [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) que carrega alguns `dropdowns` recebendo como parâmetro o nome do `dropdown`. O método está funcionando perfeitamente, pois quando "debugo" a aplicação vejo que o `dropdown` recebeu os itens. O problema é que quando coloco a chamada no `Page_Load` da aplicação mais de uma vez:

```
CarregarCombos(ddlX);
CarregarCombos(ddlY);
```

Está sendo carregado na tela somente o primeiro, porém debugando os dois estão com valores.
Resumindo: Via *codebehind* está tudo perfeito, porém em tela o `dropdown` não recebe os valores.

Isso acontece também quando tento fazer:

```
ddlX.Enabled = true;
ddlY.Enabled = true;
```

Somente o primeiro é habilitado.

Gostaria de saber o motivo e a solução para esse problema.

Comment: Qual é o código dentro do método CarregarCombos?

Comment: @FernandoPazoti poste o restante do código

Comment: Pessoal obrigado pela atenção, porém acabei resolvendo o problema. Estava com o Panel desabilitado e não estava funcionando, porém quando o habilitei, funcionou.